# Is it possible to disable autoscrolling when middle mouse button is down in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, autoscroll, mousedown

I want to get `MouseEvent` while I press down middle mouse button on a `div` and drag the cursor out of the `div`.

The problem is that when my web page is scrollable, I get scroll icon as soon as I press down middle mouse button, which I don't want.

I know calling `preventDefault()` keeps the autoscrolling from being called but it also breaks my getting `MouseEvent` if my web page is in `iframe`.

I made a simple code snippet you can try and understand the issue.

Steps;

1. Run code snippet
2. Move mouse cursor over yellow `div`
3. Press down middle mouse button

> At this point, you notice scroll is triggered.

4. Still holding middle button down, move cursor out of the yellow `div` and `iframe`

> Notice text in yellow `div` is still updated.

5. Click anywhere to disable scroll.
6. Check 'Call preventDefault' checkbox and re-run steps from #2 to #4.

> Notice text in yellow `div` is NOT updated anymore.

As you can see, `preventDefault` disables the autoscrolling but breaks the `MouseEvent`.

```js
var captured = false;
const myDiv = document.querySelector("#myDiv");
const releaseMouse = function() {
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', myHandler);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', myHandler);

  myDiv.addEventListener('mousemove', myHandler);
  myDiv.addEventListener('mouseup', myHandler);

  captured = false;
};
const captureMouse = function() {
  myDiv.removeEventListener('mousemove', myHandler);
  myDiv.removeEventListener('mouseup', myHandler);

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', myHandler);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', myHandler);

  captured = true;
};
const myHandler = function(ev) {
  const message = `${ev.type} (${ev.clientX},${ev.clientY}) ${ev.currentTarget.tagName || "Document"}`;
  switch (ev.type) {
    case 'mousedown':
      if (ev.buttons == 4) {
        captureMouse();
        myDiv.innerHTML = message;
        if (document.querySelector("#checkbox1").checked) {
          ev.preventDefault();
        }
      }
      break;
    case 'mousemove':
      if (captured) {
        myDiv.innerHTML = message;
      }
      break;
    case 'mouseup':
      releaseMouse();
      myDiv.innerHTML = message;
      break;
  }
};

myDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', myHandler);
```

```html
<div style="height: 2000px;">
  <div id="myDiv" style="width: 500px; height: 150px; background-color: yellow;"></div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1">
  <label for="checkbox1">Call preventDefault</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Firefox 85 Windows 10 When I check the `preventDefault` the text is updating

Comment: Would it possibly work to use preventDefault and then call your mouse handler manually (manually might not be the right word for this but I hope you get the gist)?

Comment: @Rojo Yes, it works okay in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Comment: @OtherMe Thanks for your suggestion the problem is our web app can run inside other people pages  whether part of the main frame or in an iframe. I want to achieve similar behaviour seen in google maps when embedded.